# Fluent UI - Nav: possibility to expand to selectedKey

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

is there a possiblity to automatically expand the nav to the selectedKey?
I am using a nested navigation, which would totally benefit from an automatic expand.
And while i found a manual solution to iterate through the items, an built-in automatic way would be awesome.

thanks